# Is the research artifact need to be powered to work (conduct research)?

Tags: dungeon-of-the-endless

Is the research artifact (crystal) room need to be powered with dust to work?

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to power the Endless Artifact room. However, if the it is on the enemies' path, consider powering it and build some defense or at least put a hero there to protect the Artifact.

[Source](http://dungeon-of-the-endless.wikia.com/wiki/Research)